# Direct from one activity to another

Tags: android

I have a userActivity java class where the user key in his username and then the page will direct to the main menu activity page after clicking the submit button. But when i click the button, it doesnt work. does any anybody know why? below are my codes.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user);

    Button submitBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    nameEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("name",nameEdit.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);  
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `it doesnt work` means ? any error?

Comment: the button doesnt work. When i click it, nothing happen. There is no error tho.

Comment: check your activity name and xml is it right ?

Comment: yeah Ive checked it for countless times but couldnt find the solution to my problem =\

Comment: change your Button id in user and check now

Comment: Is there any thing change in UserInterface after ButtonClick??

Comment: changed and checked alr but still the same =\ @ChintanRaghwani, theres no change. it is like clicking an empty button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String txt = nameEdit.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(UserActivity.this, SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("name", txt);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);  
    }
```

See if this works?

Comment: no it doesnt. is it something to do with my manifest? this is my manifest >>   <activity android:label="@string/app" android:name=".SavingsGuiderMenuActivity"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="nyp.edu.Savings2"/> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> </intent-filter> </activity>

Comment: Is that ur complete manifest?  if yes your missing the other activity & try changing <action android:name="android.intent.action.SAVINGS2"/>  if your activity java file is named Savings2 ! also copy and paste the entire manifest file in a pastebin or paste2.org and give the link if it doesnt work !                                                                                EDIT:Just noticed, in the intent u call SavingsGuiderMenuActivity java file shouldnt that be their in your manifest file?

Comment: i just realized that Im missing an activity in the manifest file. thank you so much for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the other Activity in the Manifest.xml!

Comment: You are using wrong OnClickListener from a different package.

Comment: Perhaps try instead of getBaseContext() use NameOfYourActivity.this

Answer (score 0):

replace 
`Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.class);`

with

`Intent intent = new Intent(UserActivity.this, SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.class);`

if the name of your activity is `UserActivity`

Comment: changed. But its still the same. The button wont trigger anything... =\

Answer (score 0):

Just Confirm Click is of which id to:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId() == R.id.btn_submit)  //  Confirms Your Submit Button click
            {
                Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, "Submit Button Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(UserActivity.this, SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("name",nameEdit.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);  
            }
        }
    });
```

And check Toast Message.

Comment: no it didnt. i seriously dont know why... here is my android manifest for the new intent >>>  <activity android:label="@string/app"
                     android:name=".SavingsGuiderMenuActivity">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nyp.edu.Savings2"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
                    
                </activity>